# FontForge: Count of Defined Glyphs

Tags: count, truetype, glyph, fontforge

I'm fairly new to FontForge, and I just want to merge two fonts for my specific usage.

I know how to merge two fonts from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/490922/merging-two-fonts) and I'm aware of TTF, ... 65535 lookup limits, so I'm trying to `Detach & Remove Glyphs...` for some glyph ranges, and for this:

I need to know how many glyph is defined, so I can decide which range to detach and remove. It seems fairly simple info, but I can not find where it is shown. 
is there any menu or macro to show the current number of defined glyphs in FontForge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question pops up as first Google hit, so I'll just place this for posterity, but the proper code answer is from [@Jerry Penner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55410651/1262357).

---

It's also possible from the program GUI to obtain the info in a quick dirty way:

1. Reduce the number of displayed glyphs via `Encoding > Compact` menu
2. Select the last glyph in your font
3. At the top right below the menu will be displayed the glyph "number" starting from 0 (so in below picture example the total count is 270).

Note: the number displayed is for the current compact view, not the actual glyph number in the font.

[image]

Comment: Note that if you use this method, you have to select `Encdoing > Reencode > Glyph Order` and select `Encoding > Compact`. When you select `Encdoing > Reencode > ISO-10646-1 (Unicode, Full)` and select `Encoding > Compact`, it shows a larger number than the actual glyph count. For example, it shows 66163 for Noto Sans CJK JP in my environment rather than the actual glyph count of 65535.

Answer (score 4):

I think found an answer, however it may not be the best approach. as `FontForge` saves projects in plain text, we can search for `StartChar:` keywords in the saved project file (`project_name.sfd`), which each section started by a `StartChar:` defines one glyphs in the font project. so if we count them we may know how many glyphs has been defined in the font file, for example, in `bash` the command:

```
grep -E "^StartChar\:" project_name.sfd | wc -l
```

would count them for us, and then we may know how many glyphs has been define so far.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the same info.  This will give you the number of defined glyphs fairly quickly:

```
fontforge -lang=ff \
   -c 'Open($1); SelectWorthOutputting(); Print($selection)' "$FONTFILE" \
   2>/dev/null |tr -d '][' |tr , '\n' |grep -c 1
```

The `SelectWorthOutputting()` function fills an array with ones for each defined glyph, so we can print this out and filter it to get the count.